# WCF Service that return another service

Tags: wcf

Could a WCF Service return another service ?

Code:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IServiceA
{
    [OperationContract]
    IServiceB GetServiceB();

[ServiceContract]
public interface IServiceB
{


public class ServiceA : IServiceA
{
    public IServiceB GetServiceB()
    {
        return new ServiceB();
    }
```

And a form that is activating ServiceA that calls ServiceB:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ServiceReference1.ServiceAClient client = new
            ServiceReference1.ServiceAClient();
        IServiceB serviceB = client.GetServiceB();
```

Ofcourse this cannot be done since GetServiceB() returns object and not the service when casting like this:

```
  IServiceB serviceB = (ServiceB) client.GetServiceB();
```

I get CommunicationException: "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"

Comment: Why do ypu want to do this? Just call ServiceB from the client!

Comment: I want only 1 endpoint. ServiceA is going to expose me to many objects and i dont want many endpoints

Comment: What you are looking for is a discovery service architecture

Comment: WCF is designed to handle **anything** that can be serialized into an XML message. This means: **concrete** classes of data - and that's pretty much it. Don't try to stretch WCF to support interfaces, generics, or code - that's **not** what it's designed to do.

Comment: So how can i use WCF for remote object invoking ?

Comment: @ilansch, You can't invoke ServiceB, untill you create a proxy with ServiceB's address and binding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can't.

> This simplicity for passing remote references is also one of the
> biggest dangers in .NET Remoting. In a lot of architectures, the
> transfer of remote references is not desired apart from some very
> limited and controlled cases. Passing a MarshalByRefObject instead of
> a [Serializable] object—by mistake—usually results in dramatically
> worsened performance and scalability. After all: each method call will
> now have to travel over the network, potentially spanning multiple
> cities, countries or continents.
>
> ...
>
> In WCF you can pass references to remote services but you have to be
> very explicit about doing so. It usually can't just happen without
> very clear intent.

by [Ingo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730857%28VS.80%29.aspx#netremotewcf_topic6)

So there **was** an ability ([shareable services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/magazine/cc163590%28en-us%29.aspx#S3)) to share service instance acrоss clients. Shareable was in Beta1 or Beta2 of WCF, but was cut before the final version of the product was released. But article says:

> You can re-use the .NET Remoting based IRemoteFactory interface and
> annotate it to be compatible with WCF

Preserving references (clent object graphs) [part](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730857%28VS.80%29.aspx#netremotewcf_topic8) is interesting too.

Today you can interact between clients ("share instance") with InstanceContextMode.Single (and custom client-service-client conversation logic) or with [IInstanceContextProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa354514.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

No you can't do this - your client will need the config data for ServiceB's endpoint.

Another way to approach this is to have ServiceA call ServiceB, that way your client will only need to interact with ServiceA.

Comment: Just use ServiceA as client for ServiceB